How do I make sure that a calculation is performed only once based on a unique value in a dimension in Tableau
I have produced a calculate field which calculated the percentage of a salary scale based upon how many hours that scale worked during a specific activity, for example VR. Now for each activity I want to add up all the percentages of the salary scales. Although the percentage of each scale is correctly presented by the calculated field. The visualisation sums up the values for each day that that salary worked during that activity. That need to happen only ones.
I tried this calculated field
SUM(
    IIF(
        { FIXED [MinecraftDienst], [Salaris_uniek] : SUM([Gewerkte uren]) } /
        { FIXED [MinecraftDienst] : SUM([Gewerkte uren]) } ISNULL, 
        0, 
        { FIXED [MinecraftDienst], [Salaris_uniek] : SUM([Gewerkte uren]) } /
        { FIXED [MinecraftDienst] : SUM([Gewerkte uren]) } * [Salaris_uniek]
    )
)

and I get this result in a visualisation

This adds up each percentage of each salary based upon working hours within that activity for each day and that is the problem I need to happen only once. In powerbi this happens correcly and you get this

So question is , how do I make sure in tableau dat weighted salary scale impact for each salary within for example activity vr is summed up only once, and not for each working dat of that scale in that activity
Here same sample data of the current visualitations in Tableau: 
The intention is that each outcome of the weighted Salary Scale is use only once voor each Salary Scale.
In powerbi this worked with the shown DAX formula, the data here under:

Post a little sample input data and what you want to produce for that sample data, compared to what your calculation currently provides. That way people can assist you

In general, don’t overuse LOD calculations. For example, if a field is already being used as a dimension on your visualization, say MinecraftDienst, then most of the time you don’t need to also use it in an LOD calculation, and can just use a simpler record level  or aggregate calculation. Avoid the temptation to use an LOD calc for everything just because it is similar to the SQL you already understand. Better to use the simplest Tableau calc that does the job, and let Tableau generate the SQL it needs

Thank you for the reply! As you advice I indeed made more simple caclucation, i started with a = {fixed [minecraft dienst]: sum(gewerkte uren)}. b = Proceded with {fixed [minecraft dienst],[salaryscale]: sum(gewerkte uren)}. then c = b/a and then weighted salary scale = c * [salary scale]. En then e = {fixed [minecraftdienst]: sum([weighted salary scale])}. But that gave the same result als the complete formule posted.

I would see what you could do without using FIXED at all, (i.e. No { or } either)  Write a few very simple calcs that each just answer one little part of the  question you have. That will help you identify where you have trouble. Make sure each little part is correct, then write a calculation to put them together. Again if you want more help, post some input data, the result you get for that sample input and the result you are hoping for. Its very difficult to assist you without that info

I’m not saying to never use LOD (fixed) calculations. They have a legit purpose. Just only use them when necessary since they add complexity. I’d say I need them only about 5% to 10% of the time, and even then only for part of the calculation.

@AlexBlakemore i provided some sample data i hope it makes sense

Alright, it is still hard to tell what is going on from a picture of the data, instead of a table. Can you post a packaged workbook to Tableau public and send a link.?

Are you sure you need to use sum() in all your formulas. Summing weighted salary scale sounds suspicious. You can also use min, max, avg, attr() at times, depending on your goals

Yes i would be not sounds to sum up the weighted scales of you did it for each day that each scale worked. But if you do it only once with a percentage for each scale based upon the amount of worked hours for that scale over the total for that activity it seems fine to me.

If you have exactly only the following two dimensions on one of the shelves [MinecraftDienst] and [SalarisSchaal] (and any number of measures and attributes) then the following calculated field should do what you want -- assuming I understand your question correctly.
MIN([SalarisSchaal]) * SUM([Gewertke uren]) /
MIN({FIXED [MinecraftDienst] : SUM([Gewertke uren])})

You don't always have to use SUM() for aggregating measures, and you don't always have to use LOD calcs. LOD calcs are needed only when the calculation is at different level of detail than the view.
In particular, if you know you have multiple data records for each set of dimensions that all have the same value for a field, then if you only want to access that (repeated) value, then you can use MIN(), MAX() or even AVG() since those functions all return the common value when passed a list of identical values. If you are doing calculations, then I use MIN() by convention. If you are simply displaying the common value, ATTR() is useful because it will show a "*" in those cases where there were multiple unique values.

Not quit because here you wil take have a difference in the weigted salary scale because you the the min values of the working hours
Random Manuel calc for Minecraft VR to explain my goal: lets says salary scale 1 and 10 take up al the working hours for that activity. Scale 1 takes up 40 procent and scale 1 takes up 60 procent.
So the calculation shoud be for VR for the weighted salary scale: 1 * 0.4 + 10 * 0.6 = 0.4 + 6 = 6.4
Important that the weigthed salary for each scale is only added once.
